# What does LL mean?

Tags: c++, literals, suffix

Is `LL` defined anywhere in the standard (hard term to come by)?

[ideone](http://ideone.com/ch3INx) accepts the code

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(0LL) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(0);
}
```

and prints

```
8
4
```

But what does it mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is specified in Paragraph 2.14.2 of the C++11 Standard:

## 2.14.2 Integer literals

> [...]
>
> *long-long-suffix*: one of
>
> ```
> ll LL
> ```

Paragraph 2.14.2/2, and in particular Table 6, goes on specifying the meaning of the suffix for decimal, octal, and hexadecimal constants, and the types they are given.

Since `0` is an octal literal, the type of `0LL` is `long long int`:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    // Won't fire
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(0LL), long long int>::value, "Ouch!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`LL` is the suffix for long-long, which is 64-bit on most (all?) C/C++ implementations.  So `0LL` is a 64-bit literal with the value of 0.

This is similar to `L` being the suffix for a long literal, which on most 32- and 64-bit C/C++ implementations is the same size as a non-long `int`.  (On 16-bit implementations, the size of `int` is usually 16 bits, and so the `L` suffix would indicate a 32-bit integer literal in contrast to the default of 16 bits.)

Answer (score 4):

`0LL` is an integer literal. It's suffix is `LL` which determines the possible set of types that it might have. For a decimal constant, the type will be `long long int`. For an octal or hexadecimal constant, the type will be `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` if necessary. In the case of `0LL`, the literal is of type `long long int`.

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list in Table 6 in which its value can be represented.
>
> Table 6 - Types of integer constants
>
> ```
> Suffix     Decimal constants    Octal or hexadecimal constant
> ...
> ll or LL   long long int        long long int
>                                 unsigned long long int
> ...
> ```

Comment: When do octal and hexadecimal literals become unsigned "if necessary", except when using another suffix that's not mentioned here?

Comment: @unwind When the value doesn't fit in a `long long int` but does fit inside an `unsigned long long int`. It is only considered if it doesn't fit inside a `long long int`.

Comment: @unwind When they don't fit into the signed type. Say, ints are 16-bit. 0x7fff fits into int. 0x8000 doesn't fit into int, but fits into unsigned int.

Answer (score 0):

We will begin with an example:

> std::cout << 2LL << endl;

This outcome will be 2, and this happens, because depending on the data size, and to properly fix it, we want in some situations, use a 2 as long long, and this is exactly what happens. The output given is of type long long, representing the constant int 2.

### Another suffixes are (from geeks):

**unsigned int**: character u or U at the end of integer constant.

**long int**: character l or L at the end of integer constant.

**unsigned long int**: character ul or UL at the end of integer constant.

**long long int**: character ll or LL at the end of integer constant.
unsigned long long int: character ull or ULL at the end of integer constant.