# What is meant by LL as in 1000LL?

Tags: c++, c

I came accross this statement:

```
time_t time = x / 1000LL;
```

So what does this `LL` actually mean?

Comment: i think thats the suffix for long long.

Comment: Please use the proper tag. I'm hesitant to close the question because [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575054/what-does-ll-mean) is C++ specifically, while [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036056/what-do-0ll-or-0x0ul-mean) is C. `YEAR_OFFSET` is a completely different question and I have no idea what you mean by it offhand.

Comment: @anupamb don't forget to add an answer as accepted if your problem is soved ;-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do 0LL or 0x0UL mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036056/what-do-0ll-or-0x0ul-mean)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy-pasted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809292/ull-suffix-on-a-numeric-literal), which seems to be the exact same one with the `ULL` suffix :

> From the `gcc` [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Long-Long.html):
>
> > ISO C99 supports data types for integers that are at least 64 bits wide, and as an extension GCC supports them in C90 mode and in C++.
> >     Simply write `long long int` for a signed integer, or `unsigned long
> >     long int` for an unsigned integer. To make an integer constant of type
> >     `long long int`, add the suffix `LL` to the integer. To make an
> >     integer constant of type `unsigned long long int`, add the suffix
> >     `ULL` to the integer.

It, indeed, is a suffix for the `long long int` type.

Comment: In other words, it gives the constant the type of `long long int`. By default, `1000` would have the type `int`. It's logically equivalent to `(long long int)1000`

Comment: If you can copy and paste an answer from another question and it answers this question you should flag this as a duplicate

Comment: Well, it is not a strict duplicate as this question asks for the `LL` suffix as the one I copy-pasted from talks about the `ULL` suffix, which is not the same. I agree that a simple google search would have been enough to answer this anyway... and flagging as a duplicate is debatable but seems totally acceptable.